# Define IRQ for USB keyboard?

Tags: usb, wireless-keyboards, interrupts

I think my keyboard is suffering from IRQ-deprivation.
When copying data over the network, the keys start to "stick" and "stutter"...

Is it possible to assign my keyboard a high-priority interrupt?
Something like IRQ=1?

Or any other options/ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using Unity as window-manager ?! Check please if xfce4 has the same result like in unity. It could be that xfce4 is working better together with usb-keyboards and/or usb-mouses.